# Multiple Blade X component instantiations in the same view

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-7

Can you have multiple instantiations of one Blade X component?

```
// app/view/components/foo.php

class Foo extends Component {
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    ...
```

```
// resources/views/components/foo.blade.php
<div>
    {{  $name }}
</div>
```

```
// resources/views/rootcomponent.blade.php
<x-foo name="John"></x-foo>
<x-foo name="Mary"></x-foo>
```

It says:
**Cannot declare class App\View\Components\Foo, because the name is already in use**

If you use it once - or use it without constructor / class variables, it works.
Maybe I'll go with the anonymous way, I was just curious what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that base class already has that property, so it doesn't need to be redeclared.

```
// app/view/components/foo.php

class Foo extends Component {

    /* doesn't need to redeclare base class property */
    //public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        /* doesn't need this line anymore. */
        // $this->name = $name;

        /* < Custom command line here.
             ... >

             But if there is no custom command line needed,
             then this constructor is useless,
             so no need to declare this.
          */
    }

    ...
```

Hope this could helps anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this answer is related to the [Blade X components](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components).

Comment: I think laravel framework based on php, that's right?